# Sum of Counted fields

Tags: mysql

This is my simple query. I need to ORDER my result by field1 and field2 but summed. 
So if result is as
field1=5
field2=2
and
field1=6
field2=4

it should sum them (5+2) and (6+4), (7) and (10) and then order it descending. First 10 then 7

```
    SELECT 
        COUNT(table1.ID) AS field1,  
        COUNT(table2.ID) AS field2,
    FROM table3
    LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table3.ID=table1.IDv) 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table3.ID=table2.IDv)  
    GROUP BY table3.ID
    ORDER BY field1+field2 DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mind adding one more column such as

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(table1.ID) AS field1,  
    COUNT(table2.ID) AS field2,
    COUNT(table1.ID) + COUNT(table2.ID) AS field3
FROM table3
LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table3.ID=table1.IDv) 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table3.ID=table2.IDv)  
GROUP BY table3.ID
ORDER BY field3 DESC
```